# How to use a heredoc inside a command substitution?

Tags: bash

Trying to beautify following command so I don’t have to use `\n` to signal like breaks.

```
$ http POST http://localhost/sendmail \
subject="Test" \
body=$'foo\nbar!' \
preview=true
```

Using a heredoc (the `<<EOF` syntax), I could copy paste message within boundaries resulting in predictable UX… tried following, but command fails.

```
$ http POST http://localhost/sendmail \
subject="Test" \
body="$(cat << "EOF"
foo
bar!
EOF)" \
preview=true
```

What am I missing? Thanks for helping out!

Comment: BTW, the word you want is a "heredoc". EOF isn't part of heredoc syntax, it's just a conventional value for the user-selected sigil used as part of such syntax -- you can use any sigil you want; if you start it with `<<foobar`, a line containing only `foobar` ends it.

Comment: You can use newlines in quoted strings, so `body="foo` then, on a newline `bar"` would also work (and avoid a command substitution and an external `cat` command); it will certainly look cleaner than what you're trying to do with a command substitution.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Looks promising but, ideally, one could paste message without worrying about starting with `"foo` and ending with `bar"` (meaning one could paste message between fixed boundaries).

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but there actually are boundaries: the double quotes themselves.

Comment: Thanks for helping out @gniourf_gniourf. What I meant by boundaries is that in KamilCuk’s answer, message can be pasted between `EOF` lines “as-is”. No need for first and last line to include `"`.

Comment: Maybe. Again I don't know how you're going to use this and what your design really is. Since you invoke “pasting messages”, just be careful about data injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line has to be EOF and exactly EOF nothing else.

```
$ http POST http://localhost/sendmail \
subject="Test" \
body=$(cat << "EOF"
foo
bar
EOF
) \
preview=true
```

Note that your `$(...)` undergoes word splitting and filename expansion. You might have intended to put it inside `"$(...)"` double quotes to prevent these expansions.

Comment: Thanks for helping out! Looking good, but using double quotes, if message includes `!`, command fails. Would you happen to know a way around this?

Comment: Maybe this is history expansion. That would be odd, no idea - you have to post your command, and the error message.